# Storing DateTime field in lucene document

Tags: performance, search, lucene, datefield

What is the best way to add datefield to a document (i just need YYYYMMDD)

Whats the best way to query against datefield

Im creating the datefield as the following

```
newDoc.Add(new Field("newsdate", "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
```

but it slow down searches when adding a criteria of this field.
what should i do for this field.???

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html). To use it, you need to index the DateTime as a [NumericField](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericField.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this utility class 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/query/lucene/DateField.java